# What are the participants of a dalliance called?

Tags: expressions, vocabulary

"Dalliance" usually means some spontaneous or quick romantic relationship. What do we call the participants of this relationship? "Lover" feels a bit too generic since it applies to any romantic relationship. "Friends with benefits" seems like it takes the romance out of the relationship, and in any case is a bit too casual to feel the romantic when reading the phrase.

Is there a word that avoids those problems?

Comment: Flingers—"It was just one of those things/Just one of those crazy flings"

Comment: Looking up [synonyms of **dallier**](https://www.wordhippo.com/what-is/another-word-for/dallier.html) (One who plays at courtship) the words given are mostly male terms. When I look up the first word there, [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/philanderer?locale=en) says of **philanderer**: A man who readily or frequently enters into casual sexual relationships with women; a womanizer.

Comment: I'm not sure a dalliance is necessarily romantic, it could be purely sexual. Merriam-Webster uses the word "amorous".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What do we call the participants of this relationship [of dalliance]?

1. **dallier** - Someone who amuses themselves with another person or thing. *He was a **dallier** with pretty and sycophantic women.*
2. **flirt** - A person who behaves in a flirtatious manner. *She wasn't a **flirt**; she never edged up to sex and backed off giggling.*
3. **coquet** - A man given to flirting.
4. **coquette** - A woman who trifles with men's affections.
5. **fornicator** - A person who commits or indulges in fornication.
6. **fornicatrix** - A woman who commits or indulges in fornication.

[All definitions and example sentences sourced from the SOED]

Most synonyms of **fornicator** and **fornicatrix** are derogatory and refer to women, which is strongly suggestive of the sort of cultural history we're born into.